# Android: Make a swipe imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, swipe

I am new and I try to create an imageview with swipe and a dot to show on which image you see right now(something like the image below). I can't find anything on Internet on how to implement this and I don'n know how to start. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: try first at your side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a ViewPager to handle the swype gesture.

And check that for the dots : [ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [ViewPager](http://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fanimation%2Fscreen-slide.html&ei=7MPgU4OfPM-1uATM4YLYCA&usg=AFQjCNH3Xhvi-80tWGiZ7IixBgXEB0k0RA)

And for the dot follow as Stephane Mathis suggested. :-)